# AngularJS variable not getting defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my controller I am defining a variable for eg., $scope.example.example2 = true.

But when the page loads the controller doesnt work.(for eg.,there are four div which are dependent on a variable(ng-show), but they become visible irrespective of the variable).

As soon as I remove $scope.example.example2 from the controller, everything works.

I am new to angularJS :P

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that $scope.example is not defined. Please define it first as follows :

```
$scope.example = {};
//and then define the property inside this object

$scope.example.example2 = 2;
```

This should be accessible in your controller now.